# Table number spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to implement a table with 3 rows and 6 columns, each column will consist of numbers up to 50 and it can be spinned around to pick a desired number, the desired set of numbers will be picked in the middle row of the table. Please help !

I could post am image of the actual layout but i need 10 reputation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use number pickers and just put them in a single vertical line

Comment: Thank You Tamir i see the light... @ETO i was using a GUI i made of numbers from 1 to 50 on a layout with buttons so a user can click on the desired 6 numbers but its not working soo well.